# Whata is the difference between eloquent where Employee::query()->where('id','=',9074)->get(); and Employee::query()->where('id',9074)->get();

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I generally used bellows code to query anything using where condition

```
Employee::query()->where('id',9074)->get();
```

But same output return from  bellows query too

```
Employee::query()->where('id','=',9074)->get();
```

Actually what is the main difference between this two query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, `=` is default condition in most of the statements, so either you pass it or you don't it will result in the same results. You can also avoid calling `query`:

```
Employee::where('id', 9074)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For that You need to Check out the Where function of query builder

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L596

So the arguments are

**$column**  `refers to the table column` so `id`

**$operator = null** refers to the operatores you can list of operators here 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L181

**$value = null** `Refers to the column Value  so '9074'`

**$boolean = 'and'** `Used for Chaning`

So When You Pass the laravel will check the second argument of the function and check if the value is valid operator if the valid operators are not found it will consider as **=** You can see it here

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L622

```
Employee::query()->where('id',9074)->get();
```

Since `9074` is not valid operators so it is considering as **=**

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Also you can refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses for better understand